# Why are my selectors not working inside this flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am just starting out in html and css and am not sure why my selector is not shrinking my image, can you help me out?

I created a flex-box to put both the image and the caption in, and I plan on adding a paragraph of text on the left side of the screen also in the flex-box which I will also include in the flex-box, but the problem is i can't shrink the image while it's in the flex-box without using a selector for all images instead of for this specific one, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Made the code reproducible as per requested

```css
#img-container {    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: end;
}    
#selfie {            
    flex-basis: 10%;    
    min-height: auto;    
}
#selfie-caption {    
    justify-content: flex-start;    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resume.css">
    <main id="main">
        <title>My Name</title>
        <div id="img-container">
            <figure>
                <img id="selfie" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/2010-kodiak-bear-1.jpg/220px-2010-kodiak-bear-1.jpg">
                <figcaption id="selfie-caption">An Image Of Me</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </main>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use lorempixel or placeholdit or some other 'placeholder' image service to fill out the image space with something of the same dimensions as your real picture, so we can have a [mcve].

Comment: `figure` is a block level element that in your example is the direct child of your flex container and I think maybe you're expecting its child (the img in this case) to be influenced by its grandparent flex container. What's the expected result look like? Then we can sort you out better, but to Tyler's point, some placeholder images would be nice also.

Answer (score 0):

`flex-basis` not works, because you set `display: flex` to `#img-container`. So your flex item is `figure` and not `#selfie` and `#selfie-caption`. So `flex-basis: 10%` not give a meaning for that. So should:

```
figure{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
#selfie {            
flex-basis: 10%;    
min-height: auto;    
}
```